# Does the Aid spell affect creatures engaged in combat?

Tags: spells, combat, adnd-2e

The *Bless* spell has this restriction:

> A blessing, however, affects only those not already engaged in melee combat.

...While the *Aid* spell doesn't directly say anything similar. It does, however, say this:

> The recipient of this spell gains the benefit of a *bless* spell and a special bonus of 1d8 additional hit points for the duration of the spell.

So, a *Bless* spell cast onto allies already in combat has no effect... but would the *Aid* spell ignore that limitation, and affect creatures engaged in combat?

Answer (score 1):

The revised Player's Handbook published in 1995 has this for the *Aid* spell:

> The recipient of this spell gains the benefit of a bless spell (+1 to attack rolls and saving throws) and a special bonus of 1d8 additional hit points for the duration of the spell.

RAW, by using the word "benefit" (rather than "effect"), only the bonuses from the *Bless* spell would apply (rather than the entirety of the spell's text). The parenthesis for *Aid* in later printings further emphasizes this.